# C# Searching Through a Large Word List

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I have a file containing about 170,000 words or so. What would be the best way of dealing with this in .NET?

Does it make sense to load it into a List keep in memory and search the list. Would a list of this size be an issue to keep in memory? Any suggestions in regards to loading and searching this type of list would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What's the format of the file? What is the longest word you can have?

Comment: What kind of search do you want to perform?

Comment: What about using `Regular Expression`?

Comment: 170000 words isn't much in terms of memory. Worst case, it's about 3 and half meg. Your choice of container should really be dictated by the kinds of operations you intend to perform, but I don't think memory will be much of an issue.

Comment: @spender: You don't know what the words are, so don't make that assumption. What if they are those little words on the alphabet `{A, C, G, T}` that we call DNA? And by "little" I mean around 350 MB each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it make sense to load it into a List keep in memory and search the list. Would a list of this size be an issue to keep in memory?

Unless your words are very long, memory will not be an issue here.

If you are speaking of the English language on the standard Latin alphabet then memory will not be an issue.

But you have to be specific on your word length. If you are dealing with, say, words on `{A, C, G, T}` and those words happen to be DNA then, yes, memory will be an issue.

> Any suggestions in regards to loading and searching this type of list would be appreciated.

What type of search are you doing? Are you searching for existence or are you searching for a nearest match (say, a nearest alphabetical match)? If just existence, use a `HashSet<string>`. If nearest alphabetical match, I would start with a sorted `List<string>` and do a binary search. But if your words are very long, I might consider something like a prefix tree.

The answer to this last question depends deeply on what exactly is it you are doing.

Comment: It's a csv file and I'm only trying to find a match on a word.

Comment: @user689031: How big are the words? Very likely the simple answer is to read these into a `HashSet<string>` and test for matches uses `HashSet<string>.Contains`.

Comment: The file comes from the "Enhanced North American Benchmark Lexicon", it's a dictionary essentially. http://code.google.com/p/dotnetperls-controls/downloads/detail?name=enable1.txt&can=2&q=

Answer (score 1):

Loading them into a `List<string>`, sorting and using a `BinarySearch`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Loading the whole list into memory would be the most memory intensive options, but the fastest one as well.

If you use a file stream, you pretty much have a low fixed memory overhead at the cost of slow access due to continuous IO.

It's a choice you have to make for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Anser suggeted by Jason is geat. But be aware that never do string.split on long strings. This function has performance overheads on large string. And a culprit for OOM.